# Help me chose between 2 computers

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming

Hello guys I am going to buy a prebuilded pc soon (I know I should't and it will be way more expensive but it's nothing I have control over so please don't mention that) and I can't really chose between two computers. The specs are:

//First PC// Intel Core I5-8400 Coffee Lake, Asrock Z370 PRO4, 8GB DDR4 3000MHz Adata XPG D10, EVGA Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GDDR5, 1TB 3.5" Seagate Barracuda, Cost:1,499 BGN

//Second PC// AMD Ryzen 5 1600 (3.2 GHz 16MB), ASRock A320M-DGS, NVIDIA GTX1050Ti 4GB, 16 GB DDR4 2400 MHz, 1TB 7200rpm, 120 GB SSD, Cost:1,468 BGN

These are the specs. Please give your hones opinion and also "defend" your words. I will be playing on 1080p with modern games (GTA 5, Battlefield 1, Rainbow Six Siege etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gaming, one of the most important items is the GPU. Your two choices have the same GPU so now we get into subtle items.

The next item affecting overall (general) performance is memory speed! Not memory amount. 8GB is plenty but that 1st choice has memory running at 3000MHz. So pick #1. Make sure you understand how to set the BIOS settings as this is overclocked memory because if your BIOS ever needs to be reset, the default will not be 3000 MHz.

Pick #1.

Comment: Isn't the base clock speed of the ram 3000MHz ?

Comment: I'd agree with #1 solely based on CPU; the Intel is going to do better for gaming and since that is your primary purpose, that's what I'd go with.  However, #2 is just as worthy if not for saving a few bucks and getting an SSD; the CPU is still quite capable.

Comment: I believe base standard for Coffee Lake is 2666. Note choice 2 has only 2400 MHz memory. Considerable slower RAM.